# Pine-Script + Optimize with lower timeframe, backtest

Tags: pine-script

I would to know if it is possible to make a more precise backtest by applying a lower timeframe to exit the order.

For example, I have a DAILY timeframe strategy, but exit transactions are done when the bar is closed and sometimes it is confusing when what the first Take-Profit or Stop-Loss is reached.

I tried to applicate a timeframe of one minute to affinate the Stop and Take-Profit trigger but it seems not to start in the same time of the begining of the backtest. I have plot One Minute time frame and it is programming to begin from the current time.

There is a solution to set the begining of 1 minute timeframe at the start date of the backtest ? Maybe through an upgrade of the account ? Pro toward prenium ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your strategy runs on the chart's timeframe, and that resolution dictates the finest amount of detail your strategy can use to generate and process orders on historical bars. You can use `security()` to access higher timeframe information and use that in your calculations.

When your strategy runs in the realtime bar, then you have the option of enabling order processing at a finer resolution than the chart's resolution, using [`strategy()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_strategy)'s `calc_on_every_tick=` parameter, but keep in mind that while that will work for forward testing, your backtesting will not reflect that behavior, as historical bars on TV have only OHLC information.

Comment: Hope an other update to come for a best backtest engine, at least for Premium account ^^. Thanks

Comment: @guerinremi 2 years later on, it seems they've done exactly that! See my new answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/72722933/1137085

Comment: @Glenn, I don't think so. See my reply to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

As of May 30, 2022; if you have a Premium TradingView account (the highest level) then you can make use of the new 'Bar Magnifier' feature ([ref](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/accurate-backtesting-with-bar-magnifier-31746/)), which seems to allow for this finer grain accuracy:

> Premium account holders can now obtain more realistic order fills in their strategy backtests by using The Bar Magnifier option. This tool uses intrabar inspection to obtain deeper granularity on price movement within a bar, allowing for more precise order fills.

Comment: I just bought it thinking this would solve the problem in OP but no. What it does is on the current bar everything stay the same (including the problem). On the next bar, without it enabled trading view simulates the movement on a candle (based on its color) to determine if you will hit your tp or sl first. With it enabled, that next bar has realistic data in terms of how the candle moved while it was active.