# Is it possible to call for pivot points of 5 min timeframe while using higher timeframe like 15 min?

Tags: pivot, pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I'm trying to call for pivot points of a lower timeframe (like 5 min) while I'm using the higher timeframe (like 15 min). Based on my knowledge, the `security` function can be called at a higher time frame while applying on a lower timeframe. Please, any clue?

Thank you

Comment: The way that Pine processes bars prevents what you're asking for. You can find more info on why that is in these articles: [Pine-Script + Optimize with lower timeframe, backtest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61907922/pine-script-optimize-with-lower-timeframe-backtest) and [Tradingview: Understanding Lower Time-Frames](https://backtest-rookies.com/2020/02/12/tradingview-understanding-lower-time-frames/)

Comment: Thank you Bjorn. I've ready read these articles before, and I'm understanding how timeframes work. Since not using any type of plots, PneScript leaders should come up with a function similar to " security " to collect the pivot points of the lower timeframe, then place them in an array, so they became like any elements in an array that available to use them for further analyzing. Did you get what I meant?

Comment: I understand what you mean, but even if they implemented that, it wouldn't be available for every bar, because smaller-timeframe data doesn't go as far back as higher-timeframe data.

Comment: What if you reversed your problem? When you need 5-minute data, put your chart on 5-min and then calculate the higher-timeframe datapoints from there. It's easier to obtain higher-timeframe data.

Comment: The timeframe is a technique to translate published data into such form, so higher and lower timeframes have similar data in different shapes. In the reverse case, once the data are available, then move it inside an array to represent it like an element inside an array. I believe it can be done when the PineScript recognizes to calculate in the required timeframe either high/low frames and memorize required data once it got available.